# Javascript Image Width on Scrolldown

Tags: javascript, image, width, scrolltop

I'm incredibly new to JavaScript, and honestly thought I had a solid plan-of-attack to make my logo smaller after scrolling from the top by 10px. The goal is to make the logo (normally 400px in width) get smaller (to 100px) upon scrolling down from the top.

Can anyone help me understand why this code isn't returning any visual response?

Here is the HTML markup:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link href="normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<!--<div id="header">Header</div>-->
<div id="header">
        <img id="header-image" src="logo-mockup.png">
</div>

  <p>THIS IS ALL JUST FILLER TEXT RIGHT NOW.</p>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The CSS:

```
#header {
  background-color: #f1f1f1; /* Grey background */
  padding: 30px 0px; /* Some padding */
  color: black;
  text-align: center; /* Centered text */
  font-size: 90px; /* Big font size */
  font-weight: bold;
  position: fixed; /* Fixed position - sit on top of the page */
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height:90px;
  transition: 0.2s; /* Add a transition effect (when scrolling - and font size is decreased) */
}

#header-image {
  padding: 0px 10px; /* Some padding */
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  transition: 0.2s; /* Add a transition effect (when scrolling - and font size is decreased) */
}

p {
    margin:300px;
}
```

And the JS:

```
function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 10 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 10) {
    document.getElementById("header-image").style.width = "100";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("header-image").style.width = "400";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up an `eventListener` that calls `scrollFunction` whenever the user scrolls the wheel.
A shortcut would be to just change `<body>` to `<body onscroll="scrollFunction()">`.
You could also set up an event listener in the javascript:

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(e) {
  scrollFunction();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your scrollFunction() in never called. You should add event listener for window scroll and remember to add the unit at the end for setting the width- in your case 'px'.

```
window.onscroll = function() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 10 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 10) {
    document.getElementById("header").style.width = "100px";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("header").style.width = "400px";
  }
}
```

Comment: Billiant! This is working perfectly now. Thank you so much!